# How to get cities around a location in wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have the following request for WikiData. It works fine as the results can be used but I would like to limit the results to a subset of cities ("commune de France" in this case).

The request returns any place of interest (including the river "Hérin" which is not my intent) and I need to do DISTINCT to avoid having a joint with "city" I added.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ?place ?placeLabel ?location WHERE {

   # Use the around service
   SERVICE wikibase:around { 
     # Looking for items with coordinate locations(P625)
     ?place wdt:P625 ?location . 

     # That are in a circle with a centre of with a point
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:center "Point(4.8,44.32)"^^geo:wktLiteral   . 
     # Where the circle has a radius of 20km
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:radius "20" . 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:distance ?distance .
   } .

   ?place wdt:P31/wdt:P279* ?city .

   # Use the label service to get the English label
   SERVICE wikibase:label {
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . 
   }
}
ORDER BY ?distance
```

[Try this query online](https://query.wikidata.org/#%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fplace%20%3FplaceLabel%20%3Flocation%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%23%20Use%20the%20around%20service%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Aaround%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Looking%20for%20items%20with%20coordinate%20locations%28P625%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation%20.%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20That%20are%20in%20a%20circle%20with%20a%20centre%20of%20with%20a%20point%0A%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Acenter%20%22Point%284.8%2C44.32%29%22%5E%5Egeo%3AwktLiteral%20%20%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Where%20the%20circle%20has%20a%20radius%20of%2020km%0A%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aradius%20%2220%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Adistance%20%3Fdistance%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20%3Fcity%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%23%20Use%20the%20label%20service%20to%20get%20the%20English%20label%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fdistance)

Is there is someone who can help me in just selecting places having a "P31" property (I think somethink like `wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515` will be perfect). Thanks by advance for your help.

Comment: So replace `?city` with `wd:Q484170`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `?city` with `wd:Q484170` ([Try it here](https://query.wikidata.org/#%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fdistance%20%3Fplace%20%3FplaceLabel%20%3Flocation%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%23%20Use%20the%20around%20service%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Aaround%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Looking%20for%20items%20with%20coordinate%20locations%28P625%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation%20.%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20That%20are%20in%20a%20circle%20with%20a%20centre%20of%20with%20a%20point%0A%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Acenter%20%22Point%284.8%2C44.32%29%22%5E%5Egeo%3AwktLiteral%20%20%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%23%20Where%20the%20circle%20has%20a%20radius%20of%2020km%0A%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aradius%20%2220%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Adistance%20%3Fdistance%20.%0A%20%20%20%7D%20.%0A%0A%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ484170.%0A%0A%20%20%20%23%20Use%20the%20label%20service%20to%20get%20the%20English%20label%0A%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fdistance)):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ?distance ?place ?placeLabel ?location WHERE {

   # Use the around service
   SERVICE wikibase:around { 
     # Looking for items with coordinate locations(P625)
     ?place wdt:P625 ?location . 

     # That are in a circle with a centre of with a point
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:center "Point(4.8,44.32)"^^geo:wktLiteral   . 
     # Where the circle has a radius of 20km
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:radius "20" . 
     bd:serviceParam wikibase:distance ?distance .
   } .

   ?place wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q484170.

   # Use the label service to get the English label
   SERVICE wikibase:label {
   bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . 
   }
}
ORDER BY ?distance
```

Comment: Also wd:Q15284 (_municipality_) can be used instead of wd:Q484170 (_commune of France_) which is very restrictive. `?place (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) wd:Q15284`